# Python 3: Is there an elegant way to turn a string into a 2 dimensional dict using dictionary comprehension?

Tags: python

Is there a more elegant way to achieve the same result using dictionary comprehension?

For clarification the format of `s` will always be `"foo 1=bar 2=bar"`

```
s = "foo 1=bar 2=bar"
x = s.split()

for i in x:

    if '=' not in i:
        d = {
            i:{
                x[1].split('=')[0]: x[1].split('=')[1],
                x[2].split('=')[0]: x[1].split('=')[1]
            }
        }

d
Out[27]: {'foo': {'1': 'bar', '2': 'bar'}}
```

Comment: .... dont use a comprehension if it makes you redundantly call `split`, but what happened to `"foo"`?

Comment: Where is `'test'` supposed to come from, and where did `foo` go?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are bugs in your code, so you might want to fix those before you ask us if there's a dict comprehension that produces the same incorrect result. Or perhaps you should just describe what you're trying to do.

Comment: Corrected the spelling mistake

Comment: Just to clarify: There is only one category like `foo` and space is the delimiter, never part of a dictionary key/value? An example like s = "foo oof 1=bar 2=bar 3=rab noob 2=cal 7=ole" with keys `foo oof` and `noob` will never be an input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach:

```
s = "foo 1=bar 2=bar 3=rab"
#separate the upper level key from the rest
x = s.partition(" ")    
#now create a dictionary from the lower level key/value pairs
res = {x[0]: dict(i.split("=") for i in x[2].split())} 

print(res)
>>>{'foo': {'1': 'bar', '2': 'bar', '3': 'rab'}}
```

Thought first, it could be done as a dict comprehension, but lists are not hashable.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed, I had no idea `partition` was a thing, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach implies that the string will always be of that form, i.e.,  a `dict` with a single key-value pair, whose value is another `dict` with 2 string key-value pairs. In which case, I think regex is the most straight-forward way:

```
>>> s = "foo 1=bar 2=bar"
>>> import re
>>> pattern = r"(\w+)\s+(\w+)=(\w+)\s+(\w+)=(\w+)"
>>> K, k0, v0, k1, v1 = re.search(pattern, s).groups()
>>> {K:{k0:v0,k1:v1}}
{'foo': {'1': 'bar', '2': 'bar'}}
```

Comment: @TylerCowan I suppose, although, regex is sort of the poor-man's parser. It works for a simple case like this, but if it becomes more complex, it might make sense (and then *totally* be bad ass) to write a simple parser using [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with regular expressions in Python3 for a generic solution:

```
import re
def get_dict(s):
   if re.findall('^[a-zA-Z]+$', s[0]):
     return {s[0]:get_dict(s[1:])}
   return {s[0].split('=')[0]:s[0].split('=')[-1], **get_dict(s[1:])} if s[1:] else {s[0].split('=')[0]:s[0].split('=')[-1]}
```

tests:

```
list_of_strings = ['foo 1=bar 2=bar', 'foo bar 1=bar 2=bar']
new_data = [get_dict(i.split()) for i in list_of_strings]
```

Output:

```
[{'foo': {'1': 'bar', '2': 'bar'}}, {'foo': {'bar': {'1': 'bar', '2': 'bar'}}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you wanted to do using comprehensions here is a way to do it in a more elegant way.

It assumes that your string has one key (called foo) and lot of key/value pairs for that key

you can have n number of key value pairs for the inner dict

```
s = "foo 1=bar 2=bar 3=bar"
key_value_list = [ item for item in s.split() if '=' in item]
output_dict  = {word:{item.split('=')[0]:item.split('=')[1] for item in key_value_list } for word in s.split() if '=' not in word}
print output_dict
```

output: 
    {'foo': {'1': 'bar', '3': 'bar', '2': 'bar'}}

1. The first is a list comprehension which creates a list of all words that have an '=' . This will be used to generate the key/value pairs of the inner dict
2. The second is a nested dict comprehension, the outer dict comprehension creates a dict with key= the word that does not have a '='.
3. The value of the above key (i.e. foo) is a dictionary which is created using another dict comprehension by spiting the elements of the key_value list in #1